# change line spacing/spanning in table within multirow

Tags: longtable, line-spacing, multirow

I usually use `\begin{spacing}{x}` to change the line spacing in the text, however, it does not work in the header of `longtable`, is there any solution?

Another question is that, I use `|m{16pt} @array` environment to change the width of `longtable`, however, if I use `\tablenum[table-format = 4.4]` to align the decimal within a column, the numbers will seem to be right aligned if the column is not quite large enough. My solution now is using `\hspace` to manually move the text, any method to directly align the decimal as well as center aligned within a column with specified width?

```
\setCJKmainfont{Microsoft YaHei}
\setmainfont{Microsoft YaHei}

\begin{document}

\section{\Large \bfseries Sample QC}
\vspace{-1.0em}

\begin{longtable}
{
    |m{16pt}  % type
    |m{49pt}  % name
    |m{24pt}  % all markers count
    |m{24pt}  % reportable markers count
    |m{24pt}  % undetected markers count
    |m{24pt}  % detected rate
    |m{24pt}  % confidence
    |m{24pt}  % consistency
    |m{24pt}  % unreported
    |m{24pt}  % calculated gender
    |m{24pt}  % fill-in gender
    |m{24pt}  % gender QC
    |m{24pt}  % cross match
    |m{24pt}|  % overall QC
}
\hline

      \multirow{2}{*}{类型} &
      \multirow{2}{*}{样本编号} 
      & \#使用 & \#报导 & \#未检 & 检出率 & 置信度 & 一致性 & \#未报 & 遗传 & 登记 & 性别 & 交叉 & 质控 \\
      & & ~~~位点 & ~~~位点 & 出位点 & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & 导表型 & 性别 & 性别 & 质控 & 匹配 & 结果 \\ 
    \hline\hline
\endhead

\multirow{1}{*}{对照} & \multirow{1}{*}{NTC} & \multirow{1}*{\hspace{-5pt} \tablenum[table-format = 4.4]{86}} & \multirow{1}*{\hspace{-5pt} \tablenum[table-format = 4.4]{0}} & \multirow{1}*{\hspace{-5pt} \tablenum[table-format = 4.4]{83}} & \multirow{1}*{\hspace{-10pt} \tablenum[table-format = 4.4]{0.00}} & \multirow{1}*{\hspace{-10pt} \tablenum[table-format = 4.4]{98.84}} & \multirow{1}*{\centerline{NA}} & \multirow{1}*{\centerline{NA}} & \multirow{1}{*}{NA} & \multirow{1}{*}{NA} & \multirow{1}{*}{NA} & \multirow{1}{*}{NA} & \multirow{1}*{\textcolor{red}{不合格}}\\ \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example starting with `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}` which people can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue and understand your question. Note that much of your question depends on non-standard macros and environments which mean that your minimal example should include the relevant `\usepackage` commands.